# How to get authentication header token value in ORDS apex class

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I want to get the value of authentication header in apex class to validate it in my pl sql code but not able to find the way out.
Can anyone help on this please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,
You can try using OAUTH.CREATE_CLIENT inbuild package., Please refer below url you will get some idea.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/20.3/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html

Comment: Thanks @Uthaman, I will explore this option